# Converting second order system into first order system (ODE)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

The second order equation

$\frac{d^2\vec{x}}{dt^2} = A\vec{x}\ + \vec{g}(t)$

models an earthquake's effect on a 7-story building. Let $x_j(t)$ be the displacement of the $j$th floor with respect to its equilibrium position. The ground moves with displacement $g(t)$.

Here

$\vec{x} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
\vdots\\
x_7
\end{pmatrix}$

$\vec{g}(t) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
g(t)\\
0\\
\vdots\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$ .

A *second* order $7\times7$ system in $x_j(t)$ is given by

- $x_1'' = 10(x_2- x_1- 1)$
- $x_2'' = 10(x_3- 2x_2+ x_1)$
- $x_3'' = 10(x_4- 2x_3+ x_2)$
- $x_4'' = 10(x_5- 2x_4+ x_3)$
- $x_5'' = 10(x_6- 2x_5+ x_4)$
- $x_6'' = 10(x_7- 2x_6+ x_5)$
- $x_7'' = 10(x_6- x_7)$.

Write the above second order system as a *first* order $14\times14$ system using the additional equations $v_j = x'_j$.